# what is the difference between getelementsbytagname and getelementsbyname in javascript

Tags: javascript

I recently came across these two methods for dom elements retrieval in a douglas crockford presentation but couldn't understand the difference between these two.

```
document.getElementsByTagName()

document.getElementsByName()
```

can someone please explain it to me.

the link to the video is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fv9qT9joc0M

Comment: The first selects elements with the **Tag Name** e.g `<a>...</a> //"A"` and the second elements with the matching value in their **`name` attribute** e.g: `<a name="test"></a> //"test"`

Comment: Html tag or name attribute. Btw it's camelCase.

Comment: see [TagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.tagName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.tagName) vs [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.name)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Suppose you have this HTML :

```
<input name="test" class="cssclassname">
```

You'd got it with

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')
```

or

```
document.getElementsByName('test')
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('cssclassname')
```

Also, you can call `getElementsByTagName` on elements other than document. For example the following is allowed,

```
document.getElementsById('foo').getElementsByTagName('bar')
```

But `getElementsByName` can only be called on `document`.

Notes :

- JavaScript is case sensitive, you can't write the functions like you did in your question
- those functions don't return just the element but a live [nodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/NodeList), so you'll have to iterate over the result or take the first one if you're sure it's good : `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]`
- the MDN is a good documentation for JavaScript methods. You should read [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) and [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]` and `document.getElementsByName('test')[0]` ? Methods `getElementByTagName` and `getElementByName` don't event exist.

Comment: naah these functions return sort of an array i guess which one can loop through..it was in the video i posted

Comment: @Nav not an array but an array-like object. HTMLCollection and NodeList

Comment: @dystroy hey one more thing for finding elements via CLASSNAME will the method for getting names work ????

Comment: No it won't, that's a very different type of name.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div name="alpha"></div>
<div name="beta"></div>

var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");  // Selects both divs.
var alpha = document.GetElementsByName("alpha");   // Selects the first div.
var beta = document.GetElementsByName("beta");     // Selects the second div.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Wish I can help you, please check this**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="johnsmith" id="one">
```

in this case, input is the TagName, name is this name, id is the special unique identity.

Let's me explain a better way, 
"id" is your id card, there is only one able to hold this id card(id); 
"name" is your name, but in USA  has more than one person use this name which as john smith(name). 
"input" is your category (TagName)，4example human. 
I hope you get it now. Good luck.